# Should AddRange() return a list

Tags: c#, linq

In the following code:

```
var cats = new List<string>() {"cat1", "cat2"};
var dogs = new List<string>() {"dog1", "dog2"};

var animals = new List<Animal>();

animals = (cats.Select(x => new Animal() {Type = "Cat", Name = x}).ToList().AddRange(
                        dogs.Select(x => new Animal() {Type = "Dog", Name = x}).ToList())).ToList();
```

Calling the ToList() at the end is an error, because AddRange() returns void. This doesn't seem right nowadays when using Linq type queries.

I found I could change it to `.Union()` or `.Concat()` to fix the issue, but shouldn't `AddRange()` be updated, or is there a reason for it returning void?

Comment: Typically, a *query* doesn't modify the data sources, it *only* returns data.

Comment: Note that this isn't typical LINQ syntax you've used. Yes, you've used LINQ, but you've structured the code "fluently", which is slightly different. You're saying, build a list, then add some stuff to it. That's not quite LINQ although you're using LINQ to build the first list and the stuff to add to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AddRange` changes the underlying List object. No LinQ method does that. So it's fundamentally different and should not be used in a LinQ concatination. It's return value of `void` reflects that.

Comment: The reason for doing the change and query on one line was the context of the surrounding Linq Expression (not shown) I was creating. I've changed it to use `Concat` but I appreciate that it would be better practice to do these two operations in seperate steps to keep it cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

You've answered your own question.  If you want distinct values from the two lists use Union, if you want to just join the two lists use Concat.  Once the two enumerable have been joined you can call ToList().

AddRange is a method on the List its self and isn't anything to do with LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

`AddRange` is a method on `List<T>` that pre-dates LINQ. It mutates the current list in situ and so doesn't need to return it (nor does it follow the fluent syntax style you find a lot these days). `List<T>` is not immutable, so mutating method calls are fine.

There are linq methods that can join lists together (as you've noted in the question). I would tend to not have mutating actions embedded in a linq method chain as it goes against the general idea that linq is just a query / projection set-up and doesn't "update" things.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, it is better to use [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
animals = cats.Select(x => new Animal() {Type = "Cat", Name = x})
                .Concat(dogs.Select(x => new Animal() {Type = "Dog", Name = x})).ToList();
```

Comment: You probably just want to use `Concat` here, not `Union`, as there's no need to explicitly remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed to `Concat` now, but just wanted to know why `AddRange` was not suitable